# Sending Email Through Office365 Account Using Microsoft Graph in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, graph, sendmail

Assuming you have an application registration properly configured (application) in Azure, does anybody have a concise code example of how to send a simple email, using MSGraph 5.5, using VB.net?  All code samples I can find appear to be too old and reference a method to send, which no longer works.

I have this sub, which doesn't throw an error, but never sends the email.

```
    Shared Sub SendMailGraph(sendto_name As String, sendto_email As String, subject As String, body As String)

        Try


            Dim str_client_id As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("msgraph_client_id")
            Dim str_tenant_id As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("msgraph_tenant_id")
            Dim str_secret_id As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("msgraph_secret_id")
            Dim str_secret_val As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("msgraph_secret_value")

            Dim tco As New Azure.Identity.TokenCredentialOptions
            tco.AuthorityHost = Azure.Identity.AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud

            Dim creds = New Azure.Identity.ClientSecretCredential(str_tenant_id, str_client_id, str_secret_val, tco)
            Dim gsc As New Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient(creds)

            Dim email_to As New Microsoft.Graph.Models.EmailAddress
            With email_to
                .Address = sendto_email
                .Name = sendto_name
            End With

            Dim recip As New Microsoft.Graph.Models.Recipient
            With recip
                .EmailAddress = email_to
            End With

            Dim recips As New List(Of Microsoft.Graph.Models.Recipient)
            recips.Add(recip)

            Dim bdy As New Microsoft.Graph.Models.ItemBody
            With bdy
                .ContentType = Microsoft.Graph.Models.BodyType.Html
                .Content = body
            End With

            Dim msg As New Microsoft.Graph.Models.Message
            With msg
                .Subject = subject
                .Body = bdy
                .ToRecipients = recips
            End With

            Dim rb As New Microsoft.Graph.Me.SendMail.SendMailPostRequestBody
            With rb
                .Message = msg
                .SaveToSentItems = True
            End With

            gsc.Me.SendMail().PostAsync(rb)

        Catch ex As Exception

            Dim st As String = ex.Message

        End Try

    End Sub
```

ANY HELP is greatly appreciated.  Don't know why this is so frustratingly difficult...  Thanks, in advance.